# Problema con archivo .htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo un problema con el tema de la urls amigables, cuando incluyo el archivo .htaccess, se me bloquea el servidor y me da un error interno.

He probado en Wamp y Xammpp y en un hosting remoto, yo copio el código tal cual está en el video tutorial y al profesor le funciona y a mí no. He intentado varias veces y me sigue dando error, y el rewrite module de Apache está activado.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Activar rewrite

RegriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/proyecto-poo/error/index

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*) / (.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2


</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fácil, los 2 espacios en `^(.*) / (.*)` están de más. Es como si pasaras 5 parámetros en una línea que espera 3.
Debería ser:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
```

> -y te aseguro que si tu profesor tenía esos espacios, no le funcionaba!

Comment: hola muchas gracias, pero le saque los espacios y me sigue dando error, el error es el siguiente:

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/7.3.21 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: lo raro es que el Visual Studio Code no me colorea el codigo

Comment: ahora si funciona, era eso y ademas habia escrito Regrite en vez de Rewrite